# How to add columns dynamically in jqgrid?

Tags: dynamic, jqgrid

I want add columns dynamically. Means I have got 4 buttons. Add After, Add Before, Edit and Delete. Can someone help me, how to achive this functionaliy.

Regards,

Arfan Mahmood.

Comment: You already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392618/i-want-to-add-new-columns-by-clicking-a-button-in-jqgrid

Answer (score 1):

Unload JqGrid with `jQuery("#Table").GridUnload("#Table");`

and create again.